# couting items inside tab for each corresponding data-attribute

Tags: javascript, count, tabs, custom-data-attribute

Can you please help me with this? How can I count the number of div's with 'image-item' class I have for each tabcontent and append the number to the html for the tablinks buttons corresponding to that data-id? something like London (2). Paris (1). Tokyo (3)

I have a simple example here

https://jsfiddle.net/cz87ph6w/

```js
let handleClick = e => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".active"), e => e.classList.remove("active")); // remove `active` class from every elements which contains him.
  e.target.classList.add("active");
  document.querySelector(`div.tabcontent[data-id*="${e.target.dataset.id}"]`).classList.add("active");
};

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks"), btn => btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false));
```

```html
<div class="first-tab-component">
  <div class=" tab">
    <button class="tablinks" data-id="1">London </button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-id="2">Paris</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-id="3">Tokyo</button>
  </div>
  <div data-id="1" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="image-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="2" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="image-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="3" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="image-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your loop slightly:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks"), btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
    const count = document.querySelectorAll(`div[data-id*="${btn.dataset.id}"] .image-item`).length;
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(` (${count})`));
});
```

You'll then get something like this for your button texts:

```
London (2)
Paris (1)
Tokyo (3)
```

Comment: thx a lot. that's exactly what i want. any chance you can help me with the same approach but for a select with options? https://jsfiddle.net/2df58zqc/1/

Answer (score 0):

After a look I foun some options

**JQuery:**

```
$('.tabcontent').each(function(){
  var count = $(this).children().length;
  //add count variable to correct tab
})
```

**Plain JS:**

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');

for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
{
  var count = tabs[i].childElementCount; 
  //add count variable to correct tab
}
```